# import csv file, Search values and run all value one by one

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, selenium-webdriver

I have a CSV file where email counts is 550 and I want that I open my website and search this email id and click at save button. For all 550 email process will be same.

Please suggest me how can I will be check one by one..

I use this but it's not working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        File csvFile = new File("C:\\Users\\umesh.yadav\\Downloads\\test.xls");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String line = "";
        StringTokenizer st = null;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        int tokenNumber = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arr = line.split(",");
            //for the first line it'll print
            System.out.println(arr[0]+" " + arr[1]); // h
            // System.out.println("arr[1] = " + arr[1]); // Vito
            lineNumber++;
            //use comma as token separator
        }

    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        //System.out.println("thank you");
    }   
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Can you update the question with the first rows of the csv?

Comment: i have oracle platform ..where 550  email details  , and i want to check one by one all email id from CSV File which is saved at my local machine.....